# Faster/smarter loops [Python]

Tags: python, performance, loops, nested-loops

Data file is an Excel list with 4 columns: name, position, value and price. File imported with pandas.

There are 5 different positions.

I'm trying to match all different possibilites where it can only be one from each position + one random player that has not yet been chosen.

```
def teams(x):
    positions = list(data.Position.unique())
    indices = []
    for position in positions:
        indices.append((data.Position == position).nonzero()[0])

    positions.append('Random')
    indices.append(data.index)


    for i in indices[0]:
        for i2 in indices[1]:
            for i3 in indices[2]:
                for i4 in indices[3]:
                    for i5 in indices[4]:
                        for i6 in indices[5]:
                            if i6 != i:
                                if i6 != i2:
                                    if i6 != i3:
                                        if i6 != i4:
                                            if i6 != i5:
                                                print i, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6

teams(data)
```

My problem is that my loops are too slow and I can't get the `if` statement to work so I have to make 5 different `if`s, which I assume is a pretty stupid solution.

My question is: how can I make my loops faster/smarter and how do I fix my `if` statement

Comment: you could do `if i6 not in [i,i2,i3,i4,i5]` for your if statements

Comment: How many elements are in each indices?

Comment: atm its about 10 in all expect the last one which have about 50

Answer (score 6):

You can shorten your code to three lines if you use `itertools.product()` like so

```
from itertools import product

for i in list(product(*indices)):
    if i[5] not in i[:5]:
        print i[0], i[1], i[2], i[3], i[4], i[5]
```

`product()` is equivalent to nested for loops

Comment: this code is indeed shorter but its still really slow. Is there anyway to make it faster?

Comment: @Svelic I can't think of any other way to do it. If each indices has 10 elements and the last one has 50 then you are looking at 5 million possibilities. Caching might be an option but I don't see how to apply it to this problem. Sorry